# Reaching 100 Brachos on Tisha B'av

Tags: blessing, tisha-bav

How do you reach 100 Brachos on Tisha B'av? You can't smell spices [See Here](http://%20aish.com/h/9av/oal/48964976.html), like some do for Yom Kippur, you can't eat, and you probably won't be going to the bathroom too much. So, how do you reach 100 Brachos on Tisha B'av?

Comment: Maybe go visit lots of cemeteries? Put on dozens of pairs of Tzitzit?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/75424/going-out-of-the-way-to-reach-100-brachos-in-a-day?rq=1#comment230343_75424

Comment: If answering "Amen" to *Shemoneh Esreh* counts as if you said it yourself, you would have a total of 95 brachot on that alone. Doesn't sound hard to get in another 5 somewhere in the rest of your prayers.

Comment: @DanF Don't forget 22 morning blessings

Comment: Also: this is assuming that 100 brachos is an actual obligation instead of something along the lines of a laudatory daily goal - a spiritual "fitness tracker."

Comment: Note that source only indicates a prohibition on spices at night when Havdala would have been performed. Many actually permit smelling spices during the day, though you are welcome to ask according to the other opinions.

Comment: Link isn't working for me...

Comment: You can potentially wait to Bentch on your Seudah Mafseket until after dark.

Answer (score 3):

Listen to the blessings of the chazzan, the blessings on the Torah and haftorah.

According to one opinion mentioned in [Mishnah Brurah O.C. 124:4](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49623&st=&pgnum=289) - see Mishnah Brurah commentary #20 - someone who answers "Amen" to the Chazan's repetition of Shmoneh Esreh is considered as if he had said the blessing himself.

There are 5 occurrences of Shemoneh Esreh from Ma'ariv through mincha, if you include the silent and the reptition. That's 95 blessings. Add the 22 blessings from the beginning of Shacharit, and you're well over the 100 needed.

If you don't go to shul, I counted 92 - 93 brachot. For the other 7, put on an extra few pairs of tzitzit, or, as my wife tells me, "you have to go the bathroom whether you realize it or not!". When you're done, you'll say *Asher Yatzar" (and maybe, thank your wife, too.)